# how to replace a character INSIDE the text content of many files automatically?

Tags: python, r, text, latex

I have a folder `/myfolder` containing many latex tables.

I need to replace a character in each of them, namely replacing any `minus` sign `-`, by an `en dash` `–`.

Just to be sure: we are replacing hypens **INSIDE** all of the tex file in that folder. I dont care about the tex file names.

Doing that manually would be a nightmare (too many files, too many minuses). Is there a way to loop over the files automatically and do the replacement? A solution in Python/R would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not a big fan of bash, but for this problem you should really think about the `sed` command. One example there: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-replace-string-words-in-many-files/. If you don't like bash scripts, you can make an R loop that system-calls `sed` :')

Comment: thanks! @F.Privé do you mind posting a solution? I am either on windows/linux

Comment: Following @user2722968's answer, `system("sed -i -e 's/-/–/g' /myfolder/*")` should work in R. Maybe using `*.tex` would be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sed -i -e 's/-/–/g' /myfolder/*` should work.

The **e**xpression does a **s**earch **g**lobally and replaces all `-` inside the files the shell expands from `/myfolder/*` with `–`. Sed does the change **i**n-place, that is, overwriting the original file (you need to explicitly specify a backup-file on MacOS, I can't remember the parameter though).

Absolutely no care is taken about wether or not the `-` is a verbatim hyphen or part of the latex syntax. Be aware of that.

Comment: thanks, just to be sure: we are replacing hypens INSIDE the tex file, correct? not the name of the tex file

Comment: Expanded the answer to reflect that.

Comment: thanks that is really helpful. do you think it is possible to use a regex to find the cases where the - corresponds to a proper minus (and is not tex code such as in `\cmidrule(lr){2-4}`? that is, can we specify a regex expression using `sed`?

Answer (score 2):

Try with sed

```
find /home/milenko/pr -type f -exec \
sed -i 's/-/–/g' {} +
```

from command line(if you are using Linux)

More about  [type](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/typeh.html)

The find utility -exec clause is using {} to represent the matched files.

Comment: thanks! do you mind just explaning what the `-type  f -exec` does? and the `{} +` ?

Answer (score 2):

To rename file names, use

```
rename 's/-/–/g' *
```

it will rename all the hyphens to en dash.

To replace all contents from hyphens to en dash, use

```
 sed -i 's/-/–/g' *tex
```

Answer (score 1):

Python Solution

```
import os
directory = os.getcwd()
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
  if "-" in filename:
    os.rename(os.path.join(directory,filename),os.path.join(directory,filename.replace("-","-")))
```

**New solution to replace characters inside a file**

`u2212` is unicode character for minus and `u2014` for en-dash.

```
import os
directory = os.getcwd()
import fnmatch

def _changefiletext(fileName):
  with open(fileName,'r') as file:
    str = file.read()
    str = str.decode("utf-8").replace(u"\u2212",u"\u2014").encode("utf-8")
  with open(fileName,'wb') as file:
    file.write(str)

# Filter the files on which you want to run the replace code (*.txt in this case)    

matches = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.txt'):
        matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

for filename in matches:
  print "Converting file %s" %(filename)
  _changefiletext(filename)
```

Comment: thanks! is it possible to use `glob` instead? how can I speficy a specific folder here?

Comment: also, I dont think the if - in filename is correct. I want to replace the hypen in all the tex files, irrelevant of their names

Comment: import glob / x = glob.glob("mydirectory/*.tex") should work.

Comment: thanks @aschultz. maybe you can post a soluion with that?

Comment: also, this solution actually does not seem to work at all. here we are just renaming the files. I dont care about that unfortunately! How can you change that? thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to write a solution but unfortunately I don't know how to convert from ascii to UTF8 in Python. Other than that, it works. So that is the last piece of the puzzle.

Comment: I'm sorry, your initial question seemed like to replace file name only. Please find the updated solution. I tested this code by writing a *.txt file with minus (using unicode character) and then ran this code to replace it.

Comment: `glob` in Python2 will not work recursively, so instead `os.walk` and `fnmatch` is the better solution

Answer (score 1):

First, back all your files up before removing the ".bak" in the code. I don't want to cause you to lose something, or if my script misfires, I'd like you to be able to recreate what you have.

Second, this is probably not very good Python code, because I am not an expert. But it works, if you are editing in utf-8. Because en dash is not an ASCII character, a straight replace doesn't work. I confess I'm not quite sure what's going on here, so bigger python experts may be able to sort out where I can do better.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import codecs
import glob
import re
import os

def replace_file(file):
    endash = "–".encode('utf-8')
    print ("Replacing " + file)
    temp = codecs.open("temp", "w", "utf-8")
    with codecs.open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = re.sub("-", "–", line)
            temp.write(line)
    temp.close()
    f.close()
    os.system("copy temp \"" + file + ".bak\"")

x = glob.glob("*.tex")

for y in x:
    replace_file(y)
```

Comment: thanks! but I am getting `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Hm, sorry I dropped this...it works for me on my computer, and I wasn't able to find any ways it should work. I don't know enough about the guts of python to help you. I was getting the error you mentioned with earlier versions of my code, and I think the top comment needs to be in your code, too. Sorry I couldn't have done more for you, but your question helped me learn a few things, so thanks for that.