# regex: replace hyphens with en-dashes with re.sub

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I am using a small function to loop over files so that any hyphens `-` get replaced by en-dashes `–` (alt + 0150).

The function I use adds some regex flavor to a solution in a related problem ([how to replace a character INSIDE the text content of many files automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44996829/how-to-replace-a-character-inside-the-text-content-of-many-files-automatically))

```
def mychanger(fileName):
  with open(fileName,'r') as file:
    str = file.read()
    str = str.decode("utf-8")
    str = re.sub(r"[^{]{1,4}(-)","–", str).encode("utf-8")
  with open(fileName,'wb') as file:
    file.write(str)
```

I used the regular expression `[^{]{1,4}(-)` because the search is actually performed on latex regression tables and I only want to replace the hyphens that occur around numbers.

To be clear: I want to replace all hyphens **EXCEPT** in cases where we have genuine latex code such as `\cmidrule(lr){2-4}`.

- In this case there is a `{` close (within 3-4 characters max) to the `hyphen` and to the left of it. Of course, this hyphen should not be changed into an en-dash otherwise the latex code will break.
- I think the left part condition of the exclusion is important to write the correct exception in regex. Indeed, in a regression table you can have things like `-0.062\sym{***}` (that is, a `{` on the close right of the hyphen) and in that case **I do want** to replace the hyphen.

A typical line in my table is

```
variable    &   -2.061\sym{***}&       4.032\sym{**}   &       1.236         \\
            &      (-2.32)         &   (-2.02)         &      (-0.14)
```

However, my regex does not appear to be correct. For instance, a `(-1.2)` will be replaced as `–1.2`, dropping the parenthesis.

What is the problem here?
Thanks!

Comment: Please show us all instances where you _don't_ want a replacement to happen.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data and where it fails to match/matches erroneously?

Comment: Hi thanks! @TimBiegeleisen @zwer can only think of situations like `\cmidrule(lr){2-8}` where there is a `{` close to the hyphen and to the left of it. Indeed, in a regression table you can have things like `-0.062\sym{***}`

Comment: @Noobie I attempted an answer below.  Not clean at all, but let's see if we can iterate on this until we get something which solves your actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can offer the following two step replacement:

```
str = "-1 Hello \cmidrule(lr){2-4} range 1-5 other stuff a-5"
str = re.sub(r"((?:^|[^{])\d+)-(\d+[^}])","\\1$\\2", str).encode("utf-8")
str = re.sub(r"(^|[^0-9])-(\d+)","\\1$\\2", str).encode("utf-8")
print(str)
```

The first replacement targets all ranges which are not of the LaTex form `{1-9}` i.e. are not contained within curly braces.  The second replacement targets all numbers prepended with a non number or the start of the string.

## Demo

Comment: amazing!!, but does that work with en-dashes? (not dollar signs) ultimately I want to have en-dashes instead of hyphens. Thanks!!!

Comment: @Noobie I couldn't get the demo working with en dashes due to some encoding issue.  Just replace dollar sign with en dash and it should work.  Anyway for the purposes of a demo, I think dollar sign makes the replacements clearer and easier to read.

Comment: let me try again. updated my question to provide more details on the text input. thanks again!

Comment: I am gettinge unicode errors `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 807: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: you can actually find an example table here http://www.jwe.cc/downloads/table.tex this one does not contain the exception but otherwise all the tables look alike

Comment: This is a Python encoding problem, and I won't be of much help there.

Comment: maybe using the unicode representation? u2212 is unicode character for minus and u2013 for en-dash. please look at the last question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44996829/how-to-replace-a-character-inside-the-text-content-of-many-files-automatically

Comment: I tried something like `str = re.sub(r"((?:^|[^{])\d+)\u2212(\d+[^}])","\\1\u2013\\2", str).encode("utf-8")` but this does not seem to be the correct syntax....

Comment: @Noobie See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393843/python-and-regular-expression-with-unicode

Comment: @Noobie You need to put some effort in here.  I gave you what appears to be a valid pattern, you can handle the rest.

Answer (score 1):

`re.sub` replaces the entire match. In this case that includes the non-`{` character preceding your `-`. You can wrap that bit in parentheses to create a `\1` group and include that in your substitution (you also don't need parentheses around your `–`):

```
re.sub(r"([^{]{1,4})-",r"\1–", str)
```

Comment: It's working for me in a python3 repl. Can you explain what you mean @TimBiegeleisen?

Comment: I think what @TimBiegeleisen wants to say is that this does not replace the hypen only, is that correct?

Comment: It should (I'm replacing the ascii hyphen with an X for emphasis): `In [18]: str = "(-1.2)"

In [19]: re.sub(r"([^{]{1,4})-",r"\1X", str)
Out[19]: '(X1.2)'`

Comment: thanks Adam for your help. but `re.sub(r"([^{]{1,4})-",r"\1X",  '-0.079\sym{***}')` gives `'-0.079\\sym{***}'` which will break the latex code

Comment: This will replace LaTEX code.  [See the demo here](http://rextester.com/YLEZL80905).  I think a correct regex would be much more complex than this answer.

Comment: thanks @TimBiegeleisen for your help as well. Do you mind posting a solution then?

Comment: @AdamS I have updated my question for more clarity. I feel there was some misunderstanding